# laravel5.3 restful controller show MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel-5.3

1.Create a controller.

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

2.Add a route in /routes/web.php.

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

3.Open postman using the DELETE method.

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: you think maybe the URL you are hitting would be useful?

Comment: my postman url is http://***/photos, method is delete

Comment: right, which is either a `get` or `post` route defined at that uri

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong HTTP method for the URI you are requesting. It is a simple as that.

What ever the VERB the ROUTE is defined as, is the VERB you have to use.

If a route is defined for `POST`, you have to use a `POST` method. If it is `PUT` you have to use `PUT` method, etc .....